# Why is Retrofit ignoring successful response code?

Tags: android, api, retrofit

I'm new using Restful APIs with Android, I'm using Retrofit to connect my API to my Android App, what I'm trying to do is to insert user info to my PostgreSQL database, but everytime I insert new data, my app ignores onResponse method and goes directly to onFailure despite making a successful insertion and returning code 200, How do I solve this?

I've used HttpLoggingInterceptor to log the error, but it shows code 200, which means everything is ok from server side.

Retrofit Service class (UserService)

```
public interface UserService {
    //Return list of users
    @GET("/users")
    Call<List<User>> getUsers();
    //Post new user
    @POST("/users")
    Call<User> postUser(@Body User user);
}
```

User Class

```java
public class User {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Retrofit Connection and HttpLogging Instance

```java
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();
```

FAB that triggers insertion on MainActivity

```java
FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        final User user = new User();
        user.setName("Michael");
        user.setEmail("michael@example.com");
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                userService.postUser(user).enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                        if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User successfully inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error inserting into database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can we see an example of the response you're returning?

Comment: The 200 code represents successful request, not necessarily an insertion. Show us your postUser() on rest api

Comment: Here you can see a screenshot of my insert function on my API:

http://prntscr.com/ncutfw

Comment: And here is a screenshot of the response I get: http://prntscr.com/ncuua7

Comment: After trying new solutions, this is what I get in onFailure method: http://prntscr.com/ncv10p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem after all.

I was sending a JSON response from my API, which was incorrectly formatted, and Retrofit was taking that as an error.

Here's a screenshot of my new API function: http://prntscr.com/ncyxwx

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the converter threw an exception. Print throwable error message in onFailure method. If it's just a disagreement between your converter and the data on the wire then that's an application problem that needs to fix.

Refer this for more

https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1446

**Update after seeing the screenshot**:

This is a parsing error. In response it is expecting a JSON object of user type, but current response is returning JSON string.

Comment: You can see on my code that I'm passing an object of type User, not hardcoded strings, but I'm still getting the same error.